# Describe the second cohomology group $H^2(Z_n \times Z_n. k^*)$.

Tags: group-cohomology, cohomology

I would like to write down explicitly the generating cocycles of this second cohomology group, $H^2(Z_n \times Z_n, k^*)$.  Here $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and $Z_n$ is the cyclic group with $n$ elements.

I need to know what resolution to use and how to get the formulas!

Comment: Isn't this a completely standard Kunneth theorem calculation? The resolution Sasha gave is the standard one and works fine. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would take the standard cyclic resolution of $G = Z/nZ$:
$$
\dots \stackrel{1-t}\to Z[G] \stackrel{\sum t^i}\to Z[G] \stackrel{1-t}\to Z[G] \to Z \to 0,
$$
where $t$ is the generator of $G$, and then take the tensor square of two such --- this would give a resolution
$$
\dots \to Z[G_1\times G_2]^3 \stackrel{d_2}\to Z[G_1\times G_2]^2 \stackrel{d_1}\to Z[G_1\times G_2] \to Z \to 0,
$$
where $G_1 = G_2 = Z/nZ$ and the maps are given by
$$
d_1 = (1-t_1,1-t_2),
\qquad
d_2 = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\sum t_1^i & 1-t_2 & 0 \cr
0 & 1-t_1 & \sum t_2^i 
\end{array}\right) 
$$
($t_1$ and $t_2$ are the generators of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively). 
I think you can use this for the calculations.

Comment: Sorry for such a late comment. Yet I'm a little bit confused at the term "tensor square" of two resolutions. Is there an operation called *"tensor square of resolutions"* and here is a particular example? Or this is not actually a mathematical notion? Thank you!

Comment: If you have two rings $R_1$ and $R_2$ and two modules $M_1$ over $R_1$ and $M_2$ over $R_2$, then $M_1 \otimes M_2$ is naturally a module over $R_1 \otimes R_2$ (tensor products are over the integers). Similarly, if you have two complexes $M_1^\bullet$ and $M_2^\bullet$ their tensor product is the complex with $n$-th term $\oplus_{i+j = n} M_1^i \otimes M_2^j$. This is what I mean by tensor square of resolutions.

Comment: Thank you! So we can also regard it as the total complex of a double complex $M_1^{\bullet} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M_2^{\bullet}$? (So we can get the description of the differential map in the new complex.)

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thank you! (Since when I'm checking $d_1 \circ d_2=0$ in your notation, there is a quite subtle sign issue. Maybe the second column in $d_2$ should be $(1-t_1, -(1-t_2))^{t}$ or conversely?)

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct about the sign.